# Take email value from table in query

Tags: sql

I'm trying to replace all avatars with an avatar generator.
The avatars get generated by putting your email address in the URL.

(*I've tried searching but resulted in no solution. That may be because I don't really know what to exactly search for. I hope you can help me out by either linking me an existing thread or simply giving an answer.)*

My current table has **2** columns, `avatars` and `email`

I want to replace all avatars `hello.jpg` with `//avatar.com/emailadress.png`

How can I put the users email value in the replacement query?
**I'm using MySQL as DMBS**.

This is my current query.
`UPDATE members SET avatar = REPLACE(avatar, 'hello.jpg', '//avatar.com/%.png')`

**% Would be the value of the email adress.**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just simply concatenate in the value of the email column to the second parameter of REPLACE:

```
UPDATE members SET avatar = REPLACE(avatar, 'hello.jpg', CONCAT('//avatar.com/', email, '.png'))
WHERE avatar LIKE '%hello.jpg%';
```

If you want to test it before updating the column. Have a look at the output of this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(avatar, 'hello.jpg', CONCAT('//avatar.com/', email, '.png'))
from members
WHERE avatar LIKE '%hello.jpg%';
```

Comment: Does `email` automatically grab the column value?

Comment: Yes email is the value of the column. If you don't want to run the update you can check it out with this: SELECT REPLACE(avatar, 'hello.jpg', '//avatar.com/' + email + '.png') from members

Comment: Hmm.. I ran the query but it replaced everything with 0? Any idea's? Also thanks for the help, I feel so stupid!

Comment: Returns the avatar and email values.

Comment: I see you've updated the op with 'CONCAT'. I'm not sure what it exactly does but it worked. I cannot thank you enough! Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you run this and see what it returns: SELECT REPLACE(avatar, 'hello.jpg', CONCAT('//avatar.com/', email, '.png'))
from members
WHERE avatar LIKE '%hello.jpg%';

Comment: CONCAT returns a string concatenation of the parameters.